# Step to build a built in kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver, device

I can build a loadable module and it is working with the application successfully. Now I'm trying to include this driver in kernel driver folder as a built-in driver. But when i tried this, there is no device file created in /dev folder. What are the necessary steps to do this built-in module ? Is there any modification needed in the existing module ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your question is similar to the question [Compiling a driver as a part of a kernel, not as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421970/compiling-a-driver-as-a-part-of-a-kernel-not-as-a-module?rq=1)

The answer to that question mentioned modifying the kernel Makefiles to include your module object or directory.

In summary the steps are:

1. Copy your driver source code directory under `<linux kernel
   src>/drivers`.
2. Edit the Makefile to add the line:

   `obj-y += your_driver_dir`
3. Edit the Makefile in your driver directory to add the line:

   `obj-y := your_driver.o`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to include your module into your kernel modules (not building), you need to copy `yourmodule_file.ko` under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` and give the command `depmod -a`, after this you can load your module with `modprobe`.